# Insert DATE unexpected behavior. Why?

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a function to rearrange the date format to store in the database from `d-m-y` to `y-d-m`. The raw string with the orginal date is stored correctly with the insert query, but the formatted string not.

Table structure:

```
+-------+------+
| Field | Type |
+-------+------+
| id    | INT()|
+-------+------+
| date1 | DATE |
+-------+------+
| date2 | DATE |
+-------+------+
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");
function date2Store($date) {
    $dateFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y',$date);
    return $dateFormat->format('y-d-m');
}
$dateRaw = "22-01-17";
$dateFormatted = date2Store($dateRaw);
echo $dateFormatted; // Checking how the string looks
$query = "INSERT INTO dateTest(date1,date2) VALUES ('$dateFormatted','$dateRaw')";
echo $query; // Checking how the query looks
$db->query($query);
?>
```

The result of this is:

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id |  date1     |   date2    |
+----+------------+------------+
| 1  | 0000-00-00 | 2022-01-17 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

The $query prints:

```
INSERT INTO dateTest(date1,date2) VALUES ('17-22-01','22-01-17')
```

I've checked that both are strings, the query looks correct. Why do they store different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`17-22-01` is not a valid date, therefore - depending on the configuration of your MySQL server - it won't be stored in a field with `DATE` type.

If you want to store your source format, which isn't a valid mysql date format, maybe use another field type, p.e. `varchar` .

Have a look [here into the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-literals.html) to discover what date formats are permitted by MySql - and therefore can be used in your `INSERT`-statement:

> MySQL recognizes `DATE` values in these formats:
>
> - As a string in either '`YYYY-MM-DD`' or '`YY-MM-DD`' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation character may be used
>     as the delimiter between date parts. For example, '`2012-12-31`',
>     '`2012/12/31`', '`2012^12^31`', and '`2012@12@31`' are equivalent.
> - As a string with no delimiters in either '`YYYYMMDD`' or '`YYMMDD`' format, provided that the string makes sense as a date. For example,
>     '`20070523`' and '`070523`' are interpreted as '`2007-05-23`', but '`071332`'
>     is illegal (it has nonsensical month and day parts) and becomes
>     '`0000-00-00`'.
> - As a number in either `YYYYMMDD` or `YYMMDD` format, provided that the number makes sense as a date. For example, `19830905` and `830905` are
>     interpreted as '`1983-09-05`'.

Comment: Ok, silly me, I was looking for the mistake in the wrong direction. I was formatting `y-d-m` when it's `y-m-d`. Thanks for pointing me.